# Scheme/Racket: most idiomatic way to append single element to end of list

Tags: functional-programming, append, scheme, lisp, racket

I want to append the element `b` to the list `a` (let's say `(a1, a2, ... an)`), e.g. appending the number `3` to `(1 2)` gives `(1 2 3)`

So far I've been doing
`(append a (list b))`, which is kind of long and inelegant, so I wonder if there's a "better" way...

Comment: I think `(append a (list b))` is the most idiomatic way of doing that. It’s O(n), but unfortunately, there’s nothing better than that when dealing with singly-linked lists. If you do a lot of appending, you probably want a different data structure that can handle appends more gracefully.

Comment: what do you mean `(append a (list b))` is "long and inelegant" ? The syntax is long or the actual process is inefficient or something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you building a list piecemeal, an item at a time? If so, the idiomatic way to do this is to build the list backward, using `cons`, and then `reversing` the final result:

```
(define (map-using-cons-and-reverse f lst)
  (let loop ((result '())
             (rest lst))
    (if (null? rest)
        (reverse result)
        (loop (cons (f (car rest)) (cdr rest))))))
```

Alternatively, if your list-building is amenable to a "right-fold" recursive approach, that is also idiomatic:

```
(define (map-using-recursion f lst)
  (let recur ((rest lst))
    (if (null? rest)
        '()
        (cons (f (car rest)) (recur (cdr rest))))))
```

---

The above code snippets are just for illustrating the solution approach to take in the general case; for things that are directly implementable using fold, like `map`, using fold is more idiomatic:

```
(define (map-using-cons-and-reverse f lst)
  (reverse (foldl (lambda (item result)
                    (cons (f item) result))
                  '() lst)))

(define (map-using-recursion f lst)
  (foldr (lambda (item result)
           (cons (f item) result))
         '() lst))
```

Answer (score 2):

How frequent do you have to append to the end?

If you want to do it a lot (more than cons'ing to the front), then you are doing it wrong. The right way is to flip things around: think that `cons` put things to the back, `first` retrieves the last element, `rest` retrieves everything but last, etc. Then, you can use list normally.

However, if you want to put things to the end of the list as frequent as to cons things to the front, then this is the best that you can do with one list. You could write a function to wrap what you consider "inelegant". Traditionally it's called `snoc` (backward `cons`)

```
(define (snoc lst e) (append lst (list e)))
```

Or if you prefer to implement the whole thing by yourself:

```
(define (snoc lst e)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) (list e)]
    [(cons? lst) (cons (first lst) (snoc (rest lst) e))]))
```

Note that both approaches have the same time complexity: `O(n)` where `n` is length of the list.

But if you want it to be efficient, you can use a data structure called double-ended queue, which is very efficient (constant time per operation). See http://www.westpoint.edu/eecs/SiteAssets/SitePages/Faculty%20Publication%20Documents/Okasaki/jfp95queue.pdf for more details.

Comment: [This seems like a R6RS implementation of the queue](https://github.com/ijp/pfds/blob/master/queues/naive.sls)

Comment: Not exactly. (1) a queue is capable of putting things on one side and retrieving things from the opposite side. (2) a list (or stack) is capable of putting things on one side and retrieving things from the same side
(3) a deque is capable of putting things on any side and retrieving things from any side.

Comment: The R6RS source I linked to implements a queue and I think it's the ones described in the paper. It has a in-list and a out-list where queue and dequeue is O(1) unless the out-list is empty which includes a reverse of the in-list to become the out-list (O(n)). It would easily work as a deque as well since you just add new elements on top of the out-list O(1) **UPDATE** In fact the same repo has a [deque version](https://github.com/ijp/pfds/blob/master/deques/naive.sls)