# Scheme - Appending to the end of a list

Tags: list, append, scheme, lisp

I'm very sorry for such a simple question. It's so trivial, I haven't been able to find someone online with this problem. So I'd appreciate some help.

I want to write a very simple function that takes a list and an item, and appends that item to the end of the list.

The function I wrote recursively goes to the end of the list and returns the new item. It's so frustrating that this isn't working. It's the simplest function I've ever seen

```
(define (my-append lst item)
  (if (null? lst)
    item
    (cons (car lst) (my-append (cdr lst) item))))

(display (my-append (list 1 2 3 4) 5))
```

This displays

```
(1 2 3 4 . 5)
```

I don't know why that dot is there, and it's extremely frustrating. I haven't come across it in any previous SO questions.

I just want to see

```
(1 2 3 4 5)
```

I would really really appreciate some help, because I'm extremely frustrated with this. If it helps, I'm running this code using an online compiler 
https://repl.it/languages/scheme

Comment: in hindsight :) you could experiment with it a bit, and after `(my-append (list 1 2 3 4) 5)` you could've tried e.g. `(my-append (list 1 2 3 4) (list 5 6))` and get the idea that way. so you see, your-append is a perfectly good and normal append, it just expects a list as its 2nd argument as well as the first, to append those two lists together. So without changing the definition of the function, you could just change the way you *use* it.

Comment: There are lots of [previous SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35789176/1565698) about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to end the recursion with a *list*, not an item. Instead of this:

```
(if (null? lst)
    item
```

Do this:

```
(if (null? lst)
    (list item)
```

To clarify - a list in Scheme must end in the empty list `'()`. If your recursion ends with an item, you'll get something like this in the end:

```
(cons 4 5)
=> '(4 . 5)
```

That's a `cons` *pair*. A proper list ends in the empty list:

```
(cons 4 (cons 5 '()))
=> '(4 5)
```

Which is the same as:

```
(cons 4 (list 5))
=> '(4 5)
```

By the way, this is the idiomatic way to append an item at the end:

```
(define (my-append lst item)
  (append lst (list item)))
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. I don't know why I had to end it with (list item) though. In my mind, ending it with item makes sense.

Comment: Thank you! You explained it very well.

Answer (score 3):

The `.` is there because the last pair in your resulting list doesn't have its cdr pointing to an empty list. A proper list is a chain of pairs where the last cdr in the chain points to an empty list. E.g.

```
(list 1 2 3 4 5)
# is equivalent to
(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 (cons 5 '()))))
```

But the list you're creating is

```
(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 5)))
```

You get a `.` in the list for the same reason that `(cons 4 5)` prints as `(4 . 5)`.

When writing a recursive function, you need to think the following way:

1. What is the base case of input?
2. What should the function return for that input?
3. In non-base cases, how do I simplify the input to get closer to the base?
4. How do I combine the result of the recursive call with the input?

You got this all right except for step 2.

Consider the base case:

```
(my-append '() 5)
```

This should return `(5)`, right? But your function will just return `5`. This means that you need to wrap `item` in a list in the base case.

```
(define (my-append lst item)
  (if (null? lst)
    (list item)
    (cons (car lst) (my-append (cdr lst) item))))
```

Note that the built-in `append` procedure is for appending two lists, not appending a list and a single item. Your function is the correct way to define that function.